# How to avoid boxing of a generic argument

Tags: c#, generics, boxing

Is there a way to avoid the boxing of a generic argument of a method (no interface)?

In a dummy extension method, I tried the constraint `where T : class` to force the interpretation of `T` as at least an `object` on but boxing still happens.

```
public static bool IsNull<T>(this T obj) where T : class
{
    return obj == null;
}
```

Here is the IL code:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: box !!T
IL_0007: ldnull
IL_0008: ceq
IL_000a: stloc.0
IL_000b: br.s IL_000d

IL_000d: ldloc.0
IL_000e: ret
```

Any clue?

Comment: Since you've prohibited the generic argument from ever being a value type, you can't ever create a situation in which it *is* boxed, because *it is already a reference type*.

Comment: That's why I don't understand that `IL_0002: box !!T` line...

Comment: The instruction will box the value *if the value needs to be boxed*, which it never will.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static bool IsNullObj<T>(this object obj)
    {
        return obj == null;
    }
```

This one would work but maybe your question was more generic that this specific example since you don't actually use the generic template.